# Strange error in React-Redux "can not read property forEach"

Tags: reactjs, exception, redux

I have a code which runs in `mapStateToProps` function of react component

```
model.relatedTables = relatedTables && _.mapValues(relatedTables, (attr, attrName) => { 
    const tableSettings = {
      targetKey: model.getOuterKeyName(),
      ...attr,
      name: attrName,
      attributeType: 'relatedTable'
    }

    [model.prototype, model.ItemClass.prototype].forEach(obj => {
      Object.defineProperty(obj, attrName, {
        get: getter(attrName, tableSettings),
        set: setter(attrName, tableSettings),
      })   
    })
  })
```

React throws an error **"can not read property forEach of undefined"** pointing to the second line of my code

```
const tableSettings = {
```

Obviousely there is no any `forEach` call in this line, even inside `model.getOuterKeyName()` function

pause on exception in chrome browser doesnt work

pause on caught exception works and points to the same line

```
const tableSettings = {
```

`step into` command doesn't help
How can i understand in such situation where is that mysterious 'forEach' call which caused an error? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault, i should not use square brackets without `;` after figure brackets as system thinks it is one expression

```
} // here should be ;

[model.prototype, model.ItemClass.prototype]
```

or wrap square brackets array initialization in `Array.from` method